# AngularJS isteven-multi-select limit display options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, multi-select

I am using the isteven-multi-select to display select options from DB. Unfortunatelly it could be really large array (from "a few" to "+100K" records). That is the reason why I use a smart select with a filter. Is there any way how can I set limit of rendering options to improve performance? Currently the large array drop down a js and a firefox.

My select:

```
<div isteven-multi-select
     input-model="data.select.options"
     output-model="data.select.data" 
     button-label="label"
     item-label="id label"
     tick-property="ticked"
     max-labels="4" >
 </div>
```

Controller:

```
...
DataInfoResource.query(
    function(data) {
        $scope.data.select.options = data;
        console.log(data);
    }
);
....
```

I also tried select2 but I do not find any way how to do it.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: try to focus on :  $scope.numberToArray = function( num ) {
                return new Array( num );   
            }

section....

Comment: You mean create own filter for options? And on change controll all selected options and filter `data.select.options` manually?

Comment: I think there is problem cause I would like to filter all options but display just a few of them. When I create a subset of an original array I will lost the 'filter all'.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did when the list size is more. Not sure if it would work for 100k records but still you can try. It really worked well for 6k record.
Modified the template in isteven-multi-select.js as follows

**'ng-repeat="item in filteredModel | filter:removeGroupEndMarker" class="multiSelectItem"'**

to

**'ng-repeat="item in filteredModel | filter:removeGroupEndMarker | limitTo:100" class="multiSelectItem"'**

Answer (score 0):

May be try this one:

```
<div isteven-multi-select ... max-height="250px"></div>
```

PS. I can't add a comment because the following answer