# How to set limit displayed selected using AngularJS isteven-multi-select?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using 'isteven multi select' in my project and it's great... but I have a problem and I don't know how to resolve it. I get data to select from DB; it's a lot of options.  The problem starts when I choose some of these option or all of these.

[image: ScreenShot]

I was looking for any solution, but i found only this:
[AngularJS isteven-multi-select limit display options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36712528/angularjs-isteven-multi-select-limit-display-options)
where is nothing.

May be this time sb will help?

@edit:I tried to write function by which to count number of selected elements.

My div: (is another div but problem is the same)

```
<div class="multiselect-control" 
isteven-multi-select 
input-model="vm.departmentList" 
output-model="vm.departments" 
on-item-click="vm.count( data )" 
button-label="name" 
item-label="name" 
tick-property="ticked" 
group-property="msGroup" 
translation="vm.localLang" 
orientation="horizontal"
output-properties="id">
</div>
</div>
```

Function : (something like that I don't old code :/ i write fast something new )

```
function count(data){
        vm.departmentListOut.push(data); //second array where i keep data
    if (vm.departments.length < 11){
       departments.push(data.name);
       } else {
        vm.departments = vm.departments.length;
       }
    }
```

Do not shout at me :D I'm a beginner

@edit2: it dont work becouse when i click on data it's add item to displayed info

Comment: You need to provide some code to see what you have tried so far and what exactly help you need.

Comment: OK, never mind. I found this in the documentation. I do not know how I could have missed it ...

Comment: <div isteven-multi-select ... max-labels="[number]" ></div>

Comment: Add max-labels="1". to display one item on selected button only.